# How to go to previous page php

Tags: php

Hi im creating a login screen and when the form is submitted it goes to another script.php. 
When the password is wrong i want to go back to my login screen(index.php) with an error message from the browser. how can i do it ?

**i tried this way but i doesnt work**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM studentlogin WHERE studentid = '$lecturerid' AND password = '$password'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if(!$row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

     header("Location: index.php")

}else {
    echo "Login successful";
}

?>
```

Comment: `Location: index.php?error=login+failed` then on index.php check for `$_GET['error']`.

Comment: You SQL is open to SQL injections. You should parameterize your query. Also hopefully the password is hashed.

Comment: A tip: store your error messages in session variables. Helps with URL manipulation prevention

Answer (score 1):

before you can use the SESSION, you need to start it

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['error'] = 'something went wrong';
  header('Location: /index.php');
  exit;
?>
```

and then in the index.php:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    echo $_SESSION['error'];
  }
?>
```

or

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['error'])) : ?>
  <?=$_SESSION['error']?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**In PHP, you cannot use a header after echoing!**

You should also remember to filter your variables, hash your password and use prepared statements to bind your variables to your sql, which will help you prevent SQL injection.

Comment: should both be under php tag ? sorry im new

Comment: I updated the answer to be more beginner friendly :)